# How to programmatically logout in acegi plugin in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is there a similar logic for logout using this login code:

```
// login account
def autht = new AuthToken(username, password)
def authtoken = daoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(autht)
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authtoken
```

I checked LogoutController and this is the only logic for logout:

```
redirect(uri: '/j_spring_security_logout')
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to invalidate the session:

```
session.invalidate()
```

and remove the authentication:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
```

You also need to remove their remember-me cookie if that's supported. Add a dependency injection for rememberMeServices ("def rememberMeServices") and call

```
rememberMeServices.logout request, response, null
```